# What is the keyguard in Android?

Tags: android, keyguard

I googled it and couldn't find a definition. As usual the Android documentation was very "illuminating".

Answer (score 98):

In a nutshell, it is your lockscreen.

PIN, pattern, face, password locks or the default lock (slide to unlock), but it is your lock screen.

Comment: is that the same as keyguard restricted mode? Just tried KeyGuard.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() with the phone on my lock screen and it returned false

Comment: It can also handle the SIM card's PIN, so this parameter maybe refers to that.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I had to read all above "answers" and it still wasn't clear.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 10):

Keyguard basically refers to the code that handles the unlocking of the phone. it's like the keypad lock on your nokia phone a few years back just with the utility on a touchscreen.

you can find more info it you look in `android/app` or `com\android\internal\policy\impl`

Good Luck !

Answer (score 1):

The lock screen works without keyguard  i have tested it. The home button stops working and you can't get to task manager by holding the home key. I wish they didn't develop a new process when it used to be built into system ui or whatever. I don't see the need for the change and extra process

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also found it here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html
It's seems a key-input protection mechanism which includes the screen-lock, but not only includes it. 
According to this webpage, it also defines some key-input restriction for auto-test framework in Android.