# How to hide the android keypad input 'system wide' in kitkat (Android SDK)

Tags: android

My app runs in the background. Occasionally, it needs to disable the keypad system wide (that is my app, running in the background, should not allow keypad to be used by any other apps on the phone or make keypad invisible).
Following thread tells me how to do it from my active window, but my app is running in the background
[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Code taken from following thread is not working

http://www.xplorationstudio.com/xploreandroid/?p=23

(I admit, I donot understand the notion of 'keyguard' even after reading  [What is the keyguard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689842/what-the-heck-is-the-keyguard-in-android))